# Express/node Pipe specific JSON object/s into POST request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a middleware service. When called, it provides a JSON object with certain information. I need to grab specific objects and pass that through to a new POST request. However, I'm struggling to grab it as it's outside of the scope and I think I'm just getting confused. Example below;

```
var createStory = {
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Token': Token
        },
    body: {
        current_state: req.body.data.item.user.name,
        name: 'API testing posts',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et dui a nisi molestie vestibulum non id ante. Sed aliquet neque augue, a vestibulum lectus euismod et. Maecenas porta justo quis maximus tempor. Sed ante libero, posuere vitae efficitur sit amet, feugiat at dolor.',
        story_type: 'bug',
        label_ids: [20949434]
        },
    json: true
    };
```

```
app.post('/api/something', function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.data.item.conversation_parts.conversation_parts[0].body === 'match'){
        request.post(createStory, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('error:', error);
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
            console.log('body:', body);
        });
        res.sendStatus(200);
    };
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

`current_state: req.body.data.item.user.name,` is what I'm trying to use here - I'm trying to pull the user name from the JSON object I receive and forward that into the `current state` key value pair.

The `if` statement works as it's within the scope.

I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're not very clear in your question where and how your "createStory" variable is used and adressed. Do you want your req.body with user credentials to be accessed across your app or just in this router you mentioned? You claim "createStory" to be a middleware, but it is not, it is just a variable hanging elsewhere.
2. You can not use "req" outside of router function.

If I (think) I understand your goal (which is again not clear), what you have is 3 options. Either you attach your credentials to your app to be accessed everywhere (keep in mind undefined where not applicable), like this:

```
app.post('*',(req,res,next)=>{
   req.service={'foo':req.body}
   req.body.data.item.user.name=req.user.name 
   return next()
})
```

Now it is available in all routers, just adress req.service or req.user.name in any router. Keep in mind possible conflict with passportjs (if you use it) since it uses req.user variable.

OR

you may manually add a middleware function with this parameter to any router you want, like this:

```
app.post('/api/something', middleware, (req,res)=>{
   //middleware is executed, do your job
})

function middleware(req,res,next){
  if (req.body.data.item.user.name){
  return next();
  } else {res.send('no user in request')}
}
```

OR

just put your "createStory" inside your router like this

```
app.post('/api/something', function (req, res) {
var createStory = {'foo':{'bar':{'data':req.body.data}}}
if(createStory.foo.bar.data){
//do your job}

})
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Ivan,

Thank you for your assistance. 

Apologies for not being very clear. 

The `createStory` is used in the `request.post`.

The issue I was having was the var `createStory` couldn't use - example: `req.body.data.item.user.name` as it's not defined, or, out of scope. 

I believe you may have solved my issue and I'm going to implement and test now.

Thank you kindly,

Comment: @TylerCupp did it help?

Comment: Hey Ivan, yes and no. I opened the laptop yesterday morning and realized that I was a bit of an idiot. It was simple and straightforward. 

Your post did point me in the right direction and I appreciate it.

Comment: @TylerCupp Ok then, happy to hear that. I would also appreciate if you return the favor by selecting the answer as chosen or at least vote up. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @IvanKolyhalov selected. I did try to upvote the day you responded but was given "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."